# how to lower windows RAM usage

Tags: windows-10, memory

I just want to know is there any way to make my RAM usage low or list all program that use memory?

I upgraded my RAM from 8 to 16gb, when it start the normal / start up RAM is only 2~4gb before open another app.

But now when first open is between 4~6gb usage without opening any active / big program.

This causing the fan more louder, and this annoying, also the program / service that use the ram not listed

[image: task manager show how much memory usage by system]
[image: the process detected running]
[image: already at performance setting]

This picture when I open program that I need (Chrome and VSCode) and when this happen the fan is very loud, and when the fan cannot be louder, I feels the performance is going down, usually when using it outdoor..

[image]

Comment: You have a paged pool memory leak. Everything else looks normal. Windows and hardware drivers unfortunately have a very large memory baseline. Also check out how much memory your iGPU has reserved.

Comment: Go to *Details* tab and sort on CPU. Monitor it for a minute. What process is using the CPU excessively.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean startup (msconfig - System Configuration in Admin Tools) and see what base memory is.

Add things you use and watch memory on the way. 4+ GB base memory is completely normal for any 64-bit machine.

Upgrading to 16 GB may have cause paged apps to use more memory.

Chrome is (can be) a memory hog. Memory usage does not (in my experience) cause a fan to run.

CPU intensive tasks can create high CPU which in turn, causes the fan to run.

Summary: Start clean (few things) and determine what you are running that causes your issues.

If clean startup does not solve the issue, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. Use the Keep Everything Option to begin with. Remaining options are more aggressive - the last one being essential a fresh install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error

.

Comment: when startup with or without  "startup items" the base memory is not so much different,
the one on top (memory use)  usually the antimalware or dwm and that process is very hard to kill. well if this usage is normal I'll  do downgrade first then

Comment: I amended my answer to include running a Windows 10 repair install.

Comment: in case it is a laptop with a discrete gpu, verfiy that the secons gpu is not used much. Moreover it looks to me that there is a single thread using much power